# How to avoid duplicate render() calls when using setState and redux actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

As title, i find that the following code will makes duplicate render() calls:

```
pressBtn = () => {
    console.warn("call completeUserLogin");
    // setState is going to update component state.
    this.setState({counter1: this.state.counter1+1});
    // counterTwoUpdate is going to update redux state.
    this.props.counterTwoUpdate(this.props.counter2+1);
}
```

The situation is just like i am calling setState two times. But two setState can be easily merged with 1 statement such as :

```
// Before changes (render() call two times)
this.setState({counter1: this.state.counter1+1});
this.setState({counter2: this.state.counter2+1});

// After changes (render() call only once)
this.setState({
    counter1: this.state.counter1+1,
    counter2: this.state.counter2+1
});
```

Any tricks to merge setState and redux action so that it will just makes 1 render() call ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Send action--> update store through reducers --> state will automatically be updated as connect has subscribed to updates for store changes.

Comment: Any live example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update both counters from two different places, you will cause two times to invoke `render()` method because of two different updates. First, I will recommend you to not save in state what you can achieve from props, such as redux global state. Second, I will advice you to use `setState()` for both counters, or to invoke action that will update the relevant. Then, you will invoke `render()` only once.